# iOS Image Design (sizes and asset catalogs)

Tags: ios, image, swift, assets, asset-catalog

I am developing my first app and, on the main menu, a logo appears. The logo currently resides in the form of a Pixelmator file on my desktop. Ultimately, I would like to export the logo as a vector file, but currently Pixelmator does not have the functionality.

I have decided that I will use 'Image Catalogs / Assets' to organise all my images, but I'm confused as to what all the '@2x', '@3x', 'retina' (e.t.c.) mean. It would be great if someone could produce a table as to the changes that a 100x100px image needs to go through in order to show as the highest quality on the screen.

Thank you in advance, Will.

Comment: If you want to display it in a view with dimensions 100pt by 100pt, you need a 100px by 100px version (@1x), 200px by 200px version (@2x), and a 300px by 300px version (@3x).

Comment: @Linuxios What about Retina 4 2x and what DPIs do I need to use?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Iconography.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH59-SW1) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) in the Apple docs.

Comment: And Retina 4 2x is really just a x2 retina display that happens to be 4" on the diagonal. The 4" part is only important for full screen graphics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question I made this [table](https://github.com/JVillella/ios-screen-sizes) to consolidate the information you and probably many more are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, that's incredibly helpful.